# Forcing at least one free variable to be non-zero in LP

Tags: linear-programming

I am designing a linear programming formulation with n free variables. Is it possible to design a linear constraint that forces at least of these free variables to be non-zero? Thanks

Trying absolute followed by linearization is not suitable for my formulation.

Comment: follow the [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work:

```
 yplus - ymin = sum(i,x[i])
 yplus+ymin >= 0.0001
 yplus,ymin >= 0  (bounds)
 ymin,yplus ∈ SOS1
```

I use here a Special Ordered Set of type 1 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_ordered_set). This formulation is a bit of a hack, as we forbid `sum(i,x[i])=0` to hold exactly. (A more rigorous approach would split each `x[i]` in three regions: negative, zero, positive, and then require at least one `x[i]` to be non-zero).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I also think that splitting each x[i] into three regions, (-inf, 0), 0, (0, inf), will be better. However, I could not find any better way to formulate x[i]=0. We can introduce \epsilon to make the regions (-inf, -\epsilon], (-\epsilon, \epsilon), [\epsilon, inf). But this will reduce the condition to a necessary condition. What I am trying to implement is a necessary and sufficient condition.